# Duplicate reception of message when reconnecting a socket

Tags: java, android, sockets, bufferedreader

I'm having problems with a simple java socket client: the connection is established properly and both server and client receive and send data. When the client loses connectivity for a couple of seconds, the socket is finished and reestablished. This is  done ok but in that moment, the last received message by the client (previous to the reconnection) is received again (2 receptions of the same message) with no reason.

**My code is:**

*To start the socket:*

```
Socket sock = new Socket();
sock.bind(null);
InetSocketAddress isa = new InetSocketAddress(serverIPAddress,serverPort);
sock.connect(isa, conectionTimeOut);
sock.setKeepAlive(true);

InputStreamReader isR = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream(), "UTF8");
reader = new BufferedReader(isR);

out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
    sock.getOutputStream(), "UTF8"));
```

*Reading data:*

```
public class IncomingReader implements Runnable {
    String message = "";

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Thread thisThread = Thread.currentThread();
        while (readerThread == thisThread) {
            try {
                while ((message = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    manageServerMessage(message);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(General.TAG, e.getMessage()+" "+e.getCause());
            }
        }
```

*When the connection is lost:*

```
public void stopSocket() {
    readerThread = null;
    try{
        if (reader != null){
            reader.close();
            reader=null;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(General.TAG, e.getMessage()+"    "+e.getCause());
    }
    try{
        if (out != null)
            out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(General.TAG, e.getMessage()+" "+e.getCause());
    }
    try{
        if (sock != null){
            sock.close();
            sock=null;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(General.TAG, e.getMessage()+"    "+e.getCause());
        sock=null;
    }
    readerThread = null;
}
```

Comment: If your question has been answered, or if it is no longer valid, please 'tick' to choose the most appropriate answer so everyone knows that the problem has been resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How are you re-establishing your Socket connection? I can see 2 possibilities at this stage...

1. You aren't fully removing all 'old' references before you recreate the connection. Are you creating a brand new `Socket`? `BufferedReader`? `IncomingReader` thread? etc. If there is something that you haven't recreated, it might be holding on to the previous value. If you're reusing your `IncomingReader` rather than creating a new one, it might still hold an old value.
2. If the connection is closed, how are you handling it on the Server side? If your Server is trying to send information to the Client, but the connection is broken, the Server may try to re-send the last message once the connection is re-established. Another possibility, if your Server doesn't close() the connection when it is broken, it too might be holding on to some old data.

Basically, as best as you can, you need to make sure that when the connection breaks, everything related to the connection on both the Client and the Server is completely closed and recreated using new Objects. If everything is a new Object, there's no possibility of any old data hanging around to confuse things.